# Summing Sales Based On Different Year Cases

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case-when, sql-server-2019

```
    | Product ID | YearBought | Sales | Min_Year | Max_Year |
    |      1     |    2016    |  $20  |   2011   |   2016   |
    |      2     |    2016    |  $10  |   2016   |   2018   |
    |      2     |    2017    |  $30  |   2016   |   2018   |
    |      3     |    2017    |  $5   |   2015   |   2019   |
    |      3     |    2018    |  $10  |   2015   |   2019   |
    |      3     |    2018    |  $20  |   2015   |   2019   |
    |      3     |    2019    |  $5   |   2015   |   2019   |
    |      3     |    2019    |  $30  |   2015   |   2019   |
    |      4     |    2018    |  $5   |   2018   |   2020   |
    |      4     |    2019    |  $10  |   2018   |   2020   |
    |      4     |    2020    |  $20  |   2018   |   2020   |
```

Min_Year = the year the product was first introduced

Max_Year + 1 = Product drop off year

Above is a sample of the table I'm working with. Trying to find:

- the sum of sales new products brought in the year they were first introduced
- the sum of "dropped sales" aka the sum of sales from products the year after they dropped off (had no sales). (Ex. Product brought in $15 in 2018 but had no sales in 2019, want to show $15 as dropped sales in 2019)

Expected Output:

```
    |     YearBought   | New Product Sales | Dropped Product Sales | 
    |      2016        |        $10        |                       | 
    |      2017        |                   |           $20         |  
    |      2018        |         $5        |                       |  
    |      2019        |                   |                       |  
    |      2020        |                   |           $35         |
```

was thinking something like this but it's not working. any help would be appreciated!

```
select 
    YearBought,
    sum(case when yearbought=min_year then sales else 0 end) as NewSales,
    sum(case when yearbought=max_year+1 then sales else 0 end) as DropSales
from 
    #t 
group by 
    yearbought
```

Comment: Define 'not working'. Error? Wrong output? what? Why doesn't your output include the $10 from product 2 from 2016 in the new product sales column? Is this an error on your part or is there some other logic that you did not share?

Comment: @urdearboy you are correct, new sales = $10 in 2016. I have a bunch of products and years in my real data set. The error from the above code is showing me $0 on sales for dropped products, although it is giving me the correct new sales. believe I shared all info, please let me know if more would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate the dropped product sales separately from the new product sales, then join the aggregations.  You can do this with subqueries, or, as I have done below, with common table expressions.

```
with

    droppedProds as (

        select      droppedYear = yearBought + 1, 
                    foregoneSales = sum(sales)
        from        @t t 
        where       YearBought = Max_Year
        group by    YearBought

    ),

    newSales as (

        select      YearBought,
                    sales = sum(sales),
                    newSales = sum(case when yearBought = min_year then sales end)
        from        @t t
        group by    YearBought

    )

    select      YearBought,
                n.sales,
                n.newSales,
                d.foregoneSales
    from        newSales n
    left join   droppedProds d on n.yearBought = d.droppedYear
    order by    YearBought;
```

Results in:

```
+------------+-------+----------+---------------+
| YearBought | sales | newSales | foregoneSales |
|------------|-------|----------|---------------|
|    2016    |  30   |    10    |               |  
|    2017    |  35   |          |      20       |  
|    2018    |  35   |     5    |               |  
|    2019    |  45   |          |               |  
|    2020    |  20   |          |      35       |
+------------+-------+----------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could list the dates first, then join it with the original table and do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    y.yearbought,
    sum(case when t.yearbought = t.min_year then sales end) new_product_sales,
    sum(case when t.yearbought = t.max_year then sales end) dropped_product_sales
from (select distinct yearbought from #t) y
inner join #t on y.yearbought in (t.min_year, t.max_year + 1)
group by y.yearbought
```

Comment: this works for new products but fails for dropped products. Want the sum of sales  for all products when the sales of a productid are 0 in max_year but had value in max_year-1

Comment: sum(case when t.yearbought=max_year and sales = 0 then sales where t.max_year = 1 end) as dropped_product_sales

I wish something like this would work @GMB

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the years are staggered.

```
with n as (
    select year_bought as y, sum(sales) as sales,
        sum(case when year_bought = min_year then sales end) as ns
    from T group by year_bought
), d as (
    select year_bought + 1 as y,
        sum(case when year_bought = max_year then sales end) as ds
    from T group by year_bought
)
select y, sales,
    ns as newSales, coalesce(dropped, 0) as foregoneSales
from n left outer join p on p.y = n.y;
```

or use `lead()`

```
select year_bought, sum(Sales) as Sales,
    sum(case when year_bought = min_year then sales end) as newSales,
    coalesce(lead(sum(case when year_bought = max_year then sales end))
        over (order by year_bought), 0) as foregoneSales
from T
group by year_bought;
```